# How to access HTML DOM element javascript function to another javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to ask that how I should code a Javascript function that on click to `btn_1` main function should execute and during the execution of the main function, the sub-function append to the div which I have created in the main function.

```
   document.getElementById('btn_1').addEventListener('click', main);


   function subfunc(){

        const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('it is working'));
        h1.id = 'heading';
        
    }
    function main(){
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'main-showcase'        
       
    }
```

Comment: call subfunc(div) in the main method

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Have the `subfunc` return the `h1` element; have `main` call it to get the element and append it to the `div`:

   ```js
   function subfunc() {
       const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
       h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('it is working'));
       h1.id = 'heading';
       return h1;
   }
   function main() {
       const div = document.createElement('div');
       div.className = 'main-showcase'        
       div.appendChild(subfunc());
   }
   ```
2. Have `main` pass the `div` to `subfunc` and have `subfunc` do the appending:

   ```js
   function subfunc(div) {
       const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
       h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('it is working'));
       h1.id = 'heading';
       div.appendChild(h1);
   }
   function main() {
       const div = document.createElement('div');
       div.className = 'main-showcase'        
       subfunc(div);
   }
   ```

Or really there are probably several other approaches you could take, but those are the primary two that come to mind.